# HOW TO SUBSTRING in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
21699,21712
```

I need an sub-string output as 21712

Comment: so you wanted to remove first value from input?

Comment: SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) ,

for ex : SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1)

Comment: The question is poor phrased and there are more other problems. I don't see any reason to upvote something like this... Please edit your question and make better with a description of the problem, sample, code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this sample , you have to use `charindex`(to find the index of comma) and `substring` function to get substring value

```
Declare @var varchar(50) = '21699,21712'
select charindex( ',', @var), substring ( @var, charindex(',', @var)+1, len(@var))
```

you can also use this too:

```
declare @var varchar(50) = '21699,21712'
select charindex( ',', @var), substring ( @var, charindex(',', @var)+1, len(@var))

;WITH Split_Names (Name, xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    @var name,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Names><name>' + REPLACE(@var,',', '</name><name>') + '</name></Names>') AS xmlname      
)

 SELECT       
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)') AS part1,    
 xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)') AS part2
 FROM Split_Names
```